# Using adsense with Google Web Light

Tags: android, adsense

As an adsense publisher, I have started facing problems with the launch of google web light. Although Google Web light speeds up browsing on a slow network by removing images and transcoding codes, I found that adsense ads are not loading properly and only first 3 ads on the page are displayed. Moreover Google Analytics is not loaded on these pages.

One can easily opt-out using  `Cache-Control: no-transform` in the http header however the page would be labelled to indicate to users that they may take longer to load and may use more data.

More info can be found on[this link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428).

Approach:

One solution that few sites are using is to use an user agent based approach.i.e. when a browser (Chrome browser and the Android browser (version 2.3+) gets a requests from user agent "googleweblight", it loads the transcoded page (lighter version of the page after removing images/codes) however within 2-3 seconds the page is refreshed and original version is loaded.

Can anyone one tell me how to write codes for the same (.httaccess/JS redirection)